# How many edits have I actually done?

Tags: discussion, edits, badges

I was trying to find out out my progress towards the editing badges, but I stumbled upon a weird situation.

First I went to the review page to see my progress and I got 460 edits

[image]

After that I went to the "users" page-> "editors" tab -> "all" option and I got 543 edits

[image]

Shouldn't these numbers be the same? Are some edits counting towards editing badges and some not?

Comment: Closing this as a dupe of the newer post because the answer there contains much more detail as to how the counts are calculated. Disclaimer: I wrote the answer, not having seen this question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No problem! You know better what should be done. But why not copy the answer to this question and close the other as a dupe, as it this one is older. Becouse of the views and upvotes the other question has?

Comment: There's no rule that states older questions cannot be closed as dupes of newer ones. :-) Copying over the answer would just cause more duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know for a fact that the value on the review page doesn't include deleted posts. I've got the Copy Editor badge on a number of sites, but when I look at the total there it's sometimes less than 500.

The other thing that could cause the difference is that the value on the users page might include edits to your own posts which won't be counted when checking your progress to the Copy Editor badge.

Comment: The difference between the badge progress and the editors tab is entirely down to tag-only edits, actually.